# 404 ошибка в роутах Symfony 4

Tags: php, apache, symfony

Установил симфони на OpenServer. Не работает ни 1 маршрут, кроме стартовой страницы. При прпытке перейти на любой другой - 404 ошибка.

Контроллер :

```
    <?php
// src/Controller/LuckyController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class LuckyController
{
    public function number()
    {
        $number = mt_rand(0, 100);

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

**routes.yaml**

```
app_lucky_number:
    path: /lucky/number
    controller: App\Controller\LuckyController::number
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема решена. После n-ного времени гугления я таки наткнулся на статью в доках и выполнил:

```
composer require symfony/apache-pack
```